# AWS KMS - Store/Use Ciphertext Blob

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I'm just getting myself setup with the AWS Key Management Service and am calling the method `generateDataKey`.  The method is working and returning the CiphertextBlob and the Plaintext blob.

However, the blobs are formatted something like:

```
�g�'��w�i�<��a*\B4p 1IG
```

I'm using the API so, according to the docs, it is not encoded. I'm trying to understand if the Plaintext can somehow be "decoded" in PHP so I can store it / use it without all the odd looking ASCII characters.  What I was expecting was a long string of characters and not the special characters above.  I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Thank you!

Comment: You should be Base-64 encoding and decoding the value when passing it around.

Comment: One more thing to add: please DON'T store the plain text key. It should be used to encrypt your data and then immediately discarded. From the official AWS guideline (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#data-keys): "Security best practices dictate that you should remove the plaintext data key from memory as soon as practical after use."

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a binary blob. These will need to be base64 encoded so that you'll get the expected result.

Sample code follows:

```
use Aws\Kms\KmsClient;

$options = [
    'region'                => 'eu-west-1',
    'version'               => '2014-11-01',
    'profile'               => 'default',
    'retries'               => 0,
    'scheme'                => 'https',
    'debug'                 => false
];

$kmsClient = new KmsClient($options);

$result = $kmsClient->generateDataKey([
    'KeyId' => '12345678-1234-1233-1234-1234567890ab',
    'KeySpec' => 'AES_256'
]);

echo base64_encode($result["CiphertextBlob"]);
echo "\r\n";
echo ($result["KeyId"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to encode the blobs in base64 encoding in order to conform to the API.